# How to calculate the distance between two cities by specifying the country in VBA?

Tags: excel, vba, distance

I have a VBA script that allows me to calculate the distance between two cities in kms.

This script is based on the site : `http://www.distance2villes.com/`

It works very well and quickly because I have Excel files with several thousands of cities and therefore distances to calculate each time.

The problem is that I sometimes have cities with the same name but in different European countries. Like in the example below: `Brest` that it finds in Belarus instead of finding the city in France.

```
Starting city   City of destination Distance Country
Soorts-Hossegor ST PIERRE QUIBERON  668     FR
Soorts-Hossegor ST AUSTELL          1198    GB
Soorts-Hossegor KIEL                1724    DE
Soorts-Hossegor BREST               2612    FR
Soorts-Hossegor WIEN                1850    AT
Soorts-Hossegor CHAMONIX MONT BLANC 948     FR
Soorts-Hossegor CORNWALL            1169    GB
Soorts-Hossegor CORNWALL            1169    GB
Soorts-Hossegor BREST               2612    FR
Soorts-Hossegor ROME                1556    IT
Soorts-Hossegor BOURNEMOUTH         960     GB
Soorts-Hossegor CORNWALL            1169    GB
Soorts-Hossegor ROTTENBURG AM NECKAR 1201   DE
Soorts-Hossegor LA CROIX VALMER      795    FR
```

Would it be possible to specify the name of the country in which to search to avoid this confusion when there are many cities? Or is there another faster way to calculate the distance between two cities in Excel?

```
Option Explicit

Sub Distance()
    
    Const DIST1 As String = "http://www.distance2villes.com/recherche?source="
    Const DIST2 As String = "&destination="
    Const DIST3 As String = "distanciaRuta"
    Const wsName As String = "Feuil1"
    
    'Dim w As Object: Set w = CreateObject("WINHTTP.WinHTTPRequest.5.1")
    Dim w As Object: Set w = CreateObject("MSXML2.XMLHTTP")
    Dim h As Object: Set h = CreateObject("htmlfile")
    
    Dim ws As Worksheet: Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(wsName)
    Dim rg As Range
    Set rg = ws.Range("A2", ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Offset(, 1))
    Dim Data As Variant: Data = rg.Value
    
    Dim isFound As Boolean: isFound = True
    Dim i As Long
    Dim Url As String
    Dim S As String
    
    For i = 1 To UBound(Data, 1)
        If Len(Data(i, 1)) > 0 And Len(Data(i, 2)) > 0 Then
            Url = DIST1 & Data(i, 1) & DIST2 & Data(i, 2)
            w.Open "GET", Url, False
            w.Send
            h.body.innerHTML = w.responseText
            On Error GoTo NotFoundError
            S = h.getElementById(DIST3).innerText
            On Error GoTo 0
            If isFound Then
                Data(i, 1) = Replace(Left(S, Len(S) - 3), ",", "")
            Else
                Data(i, 1) = ""
                isFound = True
            End If
        Else
            Data(i, 1) = ""
        End If
    Next
    rg.Columns(1).Offset(, 2).Value = Data
    
    Exit Sub

NotFoundError:
    isFound = False
    Resume Next

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Would it be possible to specify the name of the country?

Yes.

**Method 1: with Excel**

One way of achieving this would be with a 5th column containing a combination of city and country.

For example:
In cell E2, put `=B2&" "&D2` then fill down, to populate a new 5th column with a combination of city name and country code, with a space character in between. (You would then need to edit your code so that the routine uses this new output as the lookup base).

**Method 2: with VBA**

Another would be to concatenate city and country into one lookup string in VBA after pulling it from Excel like it is now, instead of concatenating it in Excel first like the above suggestion.

For example, you could try replacing this:

```
Url = DIST1 & Data(i, 1) & DIST2 & Data(i, 2)
```

With this:

```
Url = DIST1 & Data(i, 1) & DIST2 & Data(i, 2) & " " & Data(i, 4)
```

However, you may instead need to encode the concatenating space as `%20`:

```
Url = DIST1 & Data(i, 1) & DIST2 & Data(i, 2) & "%20" & Data(i, 4)
```

Or replace it with a hyphen instead (`-`):

```
Url = DIST1 & Data(i, 1) & DIST2 & Data(i, 2) & "-" & Data(i, 4)
```

Personally I would try the one with `%20` first. Note that none of these have been tested.

In any event you would also need to replace this:

```
Set rg = ws.Range("A2", ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Offset(, 1))
```

With this:

```
Set rg = ws.Range("A2", ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Offset(, 3))
```

... as well.

### Is there another faster way?

Not sure if it would be faster, but Excel can now do this natively without VBA by using geographical data types. This solution may require a recent software version. You may prefer to stick with your developed solution, since you mentioned it works and is fast enough. If interested you can see an example using the new functionality at https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/excel/lambda-examples-distance-between-two-cities/m-p/1952946. This example defines the calculation using the new LAMBDA function, but you can ignore this step for now and just input the full calculation shown in the example.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, what do you mean by concatenating the city and country in a 5th column? Only the first two are used to calculate the distance between the two.

As data I can have the city, the country and the postal code, I don't have precise GPS coordinates. And yes it depends on the number of cities but it's quite fast in general the treatment.

Comment: I have edited to show a possible formula approach to the new column. This combines the city and country code, with a space in between. I believe the website front end accepts these combinations (e.g. `Brest FR`) and processes them correctly, but you should test against your expectation.

Comment: Thank you for your detailed answer and your specific examples, it is a great help to me! On the other hand I tested your different possibilities with the VBA method but each time I have an error on this line as soon as I execute the macro...

Comment: Try putting the following immediately above that line in a new line that says `Msgbox(Data(i, 4))` and tell us what the dialog says when you run that. If you get a compile error, keep this new line but restore the original to what it used to be. I expect the dialog will say `FR`.

Comment: If the dialog does not say `FR`, then `Data(i, 4)` needs to be corrected so that it returns `FR`. However if `Data(i, 4)` is already correct then the URL concatenation is failing for some other reason - perhaps the space entity `%20` should be set in a constant and referred here, instead of input directly. If so, can help with that.

Comment: I put `MsgBox (Data(i, 4))` just after `url...`? Because when I run my macro I always get an error that highlights the new  line in yellow... but without specifying anything. I can send you the excel file if you prefer?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/230546/discussion-between-mathieu27-and-ed2).

Comment: Hi @ed2, I made several tests of the modifications you told me and it works great. I just noticed a problem. The cities I copy from other Excel files and then paste them into this file to calculate the distances. But I have several towns in France which in the basic files are called for example "PONT L'ABBE or DOLUS D OLERON" instead of "Pont-l'Abbé et Dolus-d'Oléron" which makes the result wrong because if I put the names correctly written with dashes and accents it finds the right distances. Do you think it would be possible to change directly in column B the bad names like these or not?

Comment: Glad to hear it is working. I suggest you now open a new question for the new problem. Perhaps if you had a list of correctly articulated names, you could write a function to strip them down into a list of basic names. This would give you the two columns and you could then insert a step to look up one from the other.

Comment: I have just asked a new one: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66902489/how-to-make-a-name-search-function-in-vba

Answer (score 0):

If you have access to all the data you can create a new column with cell formulas like `=CityRange & '-' &  CountryCodeRange` where  CityRange, CountryCodeRange are cell ranges i.e. $A$2, $C$2.

So when you query some places you sould refer to them as `CityName & '-' & CountryCode` for example : BREST-FR instead of BREST.

But if you download data from web you should check each page you download for both parameters to pick the value you want.

As I can see your code has some download part.

Comment: The data of my cities and countries I get directly from other Excel files. So I will calculate on this new column?

Comment: Either you do this work for each file, Or you can do it while your search code is running, checking value by value for these two parameters.