# How to make a name search function in VBA?

Tags: excel, vba

I have an Excel file that allows me to calculate the distances between two cities by specifying the country in which the destination city is located so that it searches in the right country and avoids making mistakes with the same city names in different countries.

I noticed a problem is that

- sometimes it **does not find** certain cities, especially in France and so it puts "`663 km`" each time because it only looks for "`FR`".
- and for some cities like Rome or Paris and Marseille it does not find anything. For *Rome* it's also due to *spelling* (`Roma`) and for *Paris* and *Marseille* it's because the added *district number* it doesn't take into account:

---

```
City of departure   City of destination Destination country code    Distance (km)   Correct names
Soorts-Hossegor      PONT L ABBE         FR                        663              Pont-l'Abbé
Soorts-Hossegor      PONT L ABBE         FR                        663              Dolus-D'Oléron
Soorts-Hossegor      DOLUS D OLERON      FR                        663              Saint-Pierre-d'Oléron
Soorts-Hossegor      PONT L ABBE         FR                        663              Rome
Soorts-Hossegor      DOLUS D OLERON      FR                        663              Paris
Soorts-Hossegor      ST PIERRE D OLERON  FR                        663              Marseille
Soorts-Hossegor      NAPLES              IT                        1740
Soorts-Hossegor      ST PIERRE D OLERON  FR                        663
Soorts-Hossegor      DAX                 FR                        40
Soorts-Hossegor      ST PIERRE D OLERON  FR                        663
Soorts-Hossegor      PONT L ABBE         FR                        663
Soorts-Hossegor      BREST               FR                        817
Soorts-Hossegor      ST PIERRE D OLERON  FR                        663
Soorts-Hossegor      PONT L ABBE         FR                        663
Soorts-Hossegor      ST PIERRE D OLERON  FR                        663
Soorts-Hossegor      ST JEAN D AULPS     FR                        663
Soorts-Hossegor      ROMA TRIGORIA       IT                        
Soorts-Hossegor      PARIS 11            FR  
Soorts-Hossegor      MARSEILLE 03        FR
```

I have added a column in my file with the names of the cities that are problematic, spelled correctly.

I would like to know if it is possible by running my script to search in this column and to correct the cities that cause problems? This last column could be changed as and when I find the names of cities that cause problems.

```
Option Explicit

Sub Distance()
    
    Const DIST1 As String = "http://www.distance2villes.com/recherche?source="
    Const DIST2 As String = "&destination="
    Const DIST3 As String = "distanciaRuta"
    Const wsName As String = "Feuil1"
    
    'Dim w As Object: Set w = CreateObject("WINHTTP.WinHTTPRequest.5.1")
    Dim w As Object: Set w = CreateObject("MSXML2.XMLHTTP")
    Dim h As Object: Set h = CreateObject("htmlfile")
    
    Dim ws As Worksheet: Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(wsName)
    Dim rg As Range
    Set rg = ws.Range("A2", ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Offset(, 2))
    Dim Data As Variant: Data = rg.Value
    
    Dim isFound As Boolean: isFound = True
    Dim i As Long
    Dim Url As String
    Dim S As String
    
    For i = 1 To UBound(Data, 1)
        If Len(Data(i, 1)) > 0 And Len(Data(i, 2)) > 0 Then
            Url = DIST1 & Data(i, 1) & DIST2 & Data(i, 2) & "%20" & Data(i, 3)
            w.Open "GET", Url, False
            w.Send
            h.body.innerHTML = w.responseText
            On Error GoTo NotFoundError
            S = h.getElementById(DIST3).innerText
            On Error GoTo 0
            If isFound Then
                Data(i, 1) = Replace(Left(S, Len(S) - 3), ",", "")
            Else
                Data(i, 1) = ""
                isFound = True
            End If
        Else
            Data(i, 1) = ""
        End If
    Next
    rg.Columns(1).Offset(, 3).Value = Data
    
    Exit Sub

NotFoundError:
    isFound = False
    Resume Next

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Improve city name search** -

Your code uses results of a French site with some pecularities. Making some modifications to the spelling in your data base allows to find cities (at least most of them) via url request .

The most typical corrections can be resolved via help function `correct()`:

- the site uses French spelling for some cities like ROMA ~~> Rome
- additional numeric district suffixes like `Marseille 11` have to be removed
- blanks have to be replaced by **hyphens** `-` connecting partial strings
- single `l` or `d` before vocals get added an apostrophe `'`
- all **accents** have to be replaced by the base character.

Change your **URL** assignment in the main sub to

```
   Url = DIST1 & Data(i, 1) & DIST2 & correct(Data(i, 2)) & "%20" & Data(i, 3)
```

calling the **help function `correct()`**:

```
Function correct(ByVal city As String) As String
    Dim i As Long
    'a) change special cities to French spelling
    Dim cities: cities = Split("Roma,Wien", ",")
    Dim cities2: cities2 = Split("Rome,Vienne", ",")
    For i = 0 To UBound(cities)
        city = Replace(city, cities(i), cities2(i))
    Next
    'b)remove numeric district suffixes
    Dim tmp: tmp = Split(city, " ")
    If IsNumeric(tmp(UBound(tmp))) Then
        tmp(UBound(tmp)) = "DELETE"
        city = Join(Filter(tmp, "DELETE", False))
    End If
    'c) insert hyphens and apostrophs
    city = Replace(Replace(Replace(UCase(city), " L ", " L'"), " D ", " D'"), " ", "-")
    'd) remove all accents
    Dim chars:     chars = Split("Á À Â Ç É È Ê Î Ï")
    Dim chars2: chars2 = Split("A A A C E E E I I")
    For i = 0 To UBound(chars)
        city = Replace(city, chars(i), chars2(i))
    Next
    'e) return function result
    correct = city
End Function
```

**Note** that the above functions only covers the most typical cases thus needing further additions.

*Have fun / Beaucoup de plaisir :-)*

Comment: Thank you for your detailed answer and your explanations! So I delete the `URL=` line and put your code instead? And yes I have other cities in European countries that also have these problems

Comment: When I do this I get an error on the line "If Len(Data(i, 1). which tells me "End sub expected"

Comment: I get no issues with your posted data samples. The `Len()` function alone can't raise the error. The error message seems to tell you that you deleted other code line() even till a closing `End Sub` here. - Did you actually replace the original code line `Url = ...` by `Url = DIST1 & Data(i, 1) & DIST2 & correct(Data(i, 2)) & "%20" & Data(i, 3)` ? @Mathieu27

Comment: Oh yes, I'm sorry, I didn't edit my code properly! Thanks to you! Do you think this renaming part won't slow down the processing of my code? Because I sometimes have more than 8500 distances to calculate at once and I try to optimize the processing time as much as possible...

Comment: In this case I'd try to split the site request from your data set. You could change your data set in a first step assigning them into a data field array and do the corrections already here via array loop. @Mathieu27

Comment: Do you have an example of what you told me to improve the processing speed of my script please?

Comment: Perfect, thank you very much for your time. I did several tests and everything works great, I added cities with their corrections in the first part of your code. @T.M.

Comment: Hello @T.M., Did you have time to look at optimising my script or not at all?

Comment: Mathieu27 - *Excusez-moi*, I thought this to be finalized due to your prior comment. Seems to me that you have integrated the function already in the first part, isn't it? Can you measure some speed improvement when executing these parts separately? Where precisely would you expect an optimization?

Comment: No problems, yes absolutely I have done several tests running the code without your fix and with it and I don't necessarily see any really significant slowdown, so it's fine. I was just thinking about whether I could improve this speed of execution or not.

Comment: @Mathieu27 Your post populates and writes a data field array which generally is a fast approach, here I don't see a possible improvement. - As Stack *Overflow* focusses mainly on a precise coding issue, you might get better help (e.g. regarding a method of html analyzis) at [CodeReview](https://codereview.stackexchange.com) by presenting working code to be optimized :-)

Comment: Thanks for the advice, I'll look into it! :)